# Jenkins Pipeline: Check status of another project last build

Tags: jenkins, build, jenkins-pipeline, status

As part of one of my build (ProjectA) I need to copy artifacts from another project (ProjectB). Currently I am taking the "last successful build".

But this poses an issue if the last builds of ProjectB are failing then the current build of ProjectA will receive outdated files.

So I would like ProjectA to receive last build of ProjectB only if this build is successful, otherwise it should fail. For this I need a command to query ProjectB last build status

I found a equivalent command to check the previous build status of the current pipeline, but not for another project.
Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following syntax:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def getJobStatus(String jobName){
    def request = httpRequest "https://<JENKINS_ADDRESS>/job/${jobName}/lastBuild/api/json"
    def requestJson = new JsonSlurper().parseText(request.getContent())
    return requestJson['result']
}
```

See [this](https://gist.github.com/paul-butcher/dc68adc1c05ca970158c18206756dab1) for example.
Also you can check the [httpRequest documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/http_request/#httprequest-perform-an-http-request-and-return-a-response-object).